# How can I detect the current tab's mime type in a Mozilla Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon, mime-types, firefox-addon-sdk, pdf.js

I'm trying to do the same thing as asked in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921175/how-can-i-detect-the-current-tabs-mime-type-in-a-google-chrome-extension), the only signification difference being the use of Mozilla Firefox instead of Google Chrome / Chromium .

I've tried using the [Mozilla JetPack](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Jetpack) SDK and so far, for all content loaded with Mozilla's pdf.js viewer seems to be read as `text/html` . Is there a correct way to do this using Jetpack (or even XUL) in Firefox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can detect a pdf rendered with pdf.js by checking if the `document.baseURI` property is set to `"resource://pdf.js/web/"`