# Chrome extension - saving PDF file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension that will save files to the downloads folder (that's not all it's doing, but that's the part I have trouble with). Right now I'm focusing on PDF files. Basically, when a PDF is opened in Chrome, the user can manually save it using `Menu -> Save File As` ..., I'm just trying to automate this functionality using the extension, but I haven't found a good way to do it.

Let's say I can detect if the current tab has a PDF file in it (based on answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921175/how-can-i-detect-the-current-tabs-mime-type-in-a-google-chrome-extension) question).

The best thing I have figured out so far is to initiate a download:

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: tabs[0].url, saveAs: false,
    filename: "my file", /* This will be some unique autogenerated identifier */
    conflictAction: "overwrite"
});
```

This works but has 2 drawbacks:

- The file has to be re-downloaded, which is a pain if it's large. Besides, the file has been downloaded already so I should be able to use it.
- For some reason this doesn't work with files opened locally ("file://..."). It throws a NETWORK_INVALID_REQUEST and doesn't download.

Is there a better way to save the file?

Comment: I havent found a way, through an API, to access the local files saved somewhere on your device. Some solutions pointed to NPAPI, but this is now deprecated.

Comment: @Rivero: I actually don't need to access (read) the local file. I just need to save the opened PDF somewhere and get the file location on the drive, which the download API can do. However, it suffers from the problems I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Note, chromium / chrome browsers appear to append `embed` element to `document.body` to display `.pdf` files

1. a) detecting `pdf` utilizing `window.location.href` , `document.querySelectorAll("embed")[0].type`;

   b) utilizing `XMLHttpRequest` to request existing `document`, which should return `pdf` `document` as `blob` response, from `cache`; see `console` -> `Network` -> `Headers` -> `Status Code`
2. To allow opening `file:` `protocol` at chromium / chrome browsers, try utilizing command line flag `--allow-access-from-files`; see [How do I make the Google Chrome flag “--allow-file-access-from-files” permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/)

---

At `.pdf` `document` , i.e.g; [Ecma-262.pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) try

```
// check if `document` is `pdf`
if (/pdf/i.test(window.location.href.slice(-3)) 
    || document.querySelectorAll("embed")[0].type === "application/pdf") {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // load `document` from `cache`
    xhr.open("GET", "", true); 
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            // `blob` response
            console.log(this.response);
            var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = file;
            a.download = this.response.name 
                        || document.querySelectorAll("embed")[0].src
                           .split("/").pop();
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            // remove `a` following `Save As` dialog, 
            // `window` regains `focus`
            window.onfocus = function () {                     
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a")
                , function (el) {
                    document.body.removeChild(el)
                })
            }
        };
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: The `XMLHttpRequest` getting the file from cache sounds useful, I'll give that a try. My only concern is a case when the PDF is generated by the server as a result of a POST request, the GET might not give me the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing only the file:// aspect of your problem.  Does your extension have permission to access file://.  In order to have access your extension both needs to ask for file://*/* and user has to manually grant this access from the extensions page.  You can check if you have the requisite permission using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-isAllowedFileSchemeAccess.

See [Adding file://. permission to chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493020/adding-file-permission-to-chrome-extension) for more information about accessing file:// urls.  You may also find [How can I enable my chrome extension in incognito mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438354/how-can-i-enable-my-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode/17443982#17443982) helpful.

For a related discussion (although not specific for your use case since you already have a PDF file), also see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=169337.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links. The file:// is actually not so hard to solve, because the point of the extension is to get the currently opened files to the disk. If it's file://, it's there already, so I can just use it. I would prefer to have a single way to save http:// and file:// PDFs, but I'll have to make a special case for file://, because I can't expect our users to go messing around in settings.