# How to capture PDF contents using Chrome Extension API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome Extension, and I need a way of saving the contents of the current page, whether it's an HTML page or a PDF page.

For HTML, I can use  chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML, however, this does not work if the current page is a PDF document. I've been searching for a way to dump the PDF from Chrome's PDFViewer, but I've found absolutely no information on it.

The one requirement I have is that I can't issue a second request, as the PDF is the response from a form submission, and a second request would re-submit the form causing duplicate data. This system is out of my control, so I can't change the behavior.

Comment: Sorry for my eng. I don't understand, you want just download pdf document or detect pdf page?

Comment: I'd like to be able to programatically save the PDF to a specific location, without issuing a second HTTP request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension - saving PDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114794/chrome-extension-saving-pdf-file)

Comment: The approach in the "duplicate" answer requires a second request, which I've said won't work for my approach