# Run a Chrome Plugin On a PDF Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

Using a Chrome extension, I'd like to:

1. Detect if the current tab has loaded a PDF file.
2. Add a button to the popup.html to offer to convert the PDF into HTML5.
3. Get the URL of the PDF file and send that to an online service.

To accomplish #1, I think one of the solutions on this page could work: 
[How can I detect the current tab's mime type in a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921175/how-can-i-detect-the-current-tabs-mime-type-in-a-google-chrome-extension)

The problem is that I'm having trouble getting the extension to run on the PDF page itself.

How do I run `background.js` of the extension on the PDF page?

My manifest file currently:

```
{
   "matches":[
      "https://*/*",
      "http://*/*"
   ],
   "run_at":"document_idle",
   "css":[
      "jquery-ui.css",
      "resizable.css"
   ],
   "js":[
      "jquery.js",
      "jquery-ui.js",
      "storage.js",
      "background.js"
   ],
   "all_frames":true
}
```

Comment: You might want to [re]read the extension architecture article because the background page is an entirely different page (you can think of it as of a hidden browser tab that has its own DOM and scripts). By using such a misleading file name you're probably missing the simple solution which is to check the presence of `body > embed[name="plugin"][type="application/pdf"]` as you can see in the devtools inspector on a pdf page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest file you should have this:

```
"content_scripts": [
 {
   "matches": ["*://*.pdf"],
   "js": ["background.js"]
 }
]
```

Comment: This is my manifest file currently - ````{
            "matches":[ "https://*/*","http://*/*"],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "css":["jquery-ui.css","resizable.css"],
            "js": ["jquery.js","jquery-ui.js","storage.js","background.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        },````

Comment: You'd think it would match a PDF as well (note - the PDFs don't always have a .pdf on the end)

Comment: What's the issue? The `background.js` doesn't load on pages ending with `.pdf` ?

Comment: Yes - the background.js doesn't load on the chrome PDF viewer.

Comment: Did you make sure it's opened on `http` and not `file:///`?

Comment: Yep :) I'm setting up a test extension with everything else stripped out just to eliminate any other possibilities.

Comment: If your `background.js` is same as the question you have linked to, then you must have the `permissions` added to your manifest as well.

Comment: That did it. Should have thought of that. Thanks!